# Polars join with or condition

Tags: python, python-polars

I have two dataset coming from two very different data sources.

Dataframe 1

```
┌────────────┬─────────────────┬─────────────────┬─────────────────┬────────────────┬──────────────┐
│ date       ┆ label           ┆ org_slug        ┆ org_id          ┆ org_name       ┆ issues_count │
│ ---        ┆ ---             ┆ ---             ┆ ---             ┆ ---            ┆ ---          │
│ date       ┆ str             ┆ str             ┆ str             ┆ str            ┆ i64          │
╞════════════╪═════════════════╪═════════════════╪═════════════════╪════════════════╪══════════════╡
│ 2023-08-29 ┆ label1          ┆ org-slug-name-1 ┆ org-id-1        ┆ org-name       ┆ 1            │          │
└────────────┴─────────────────┴─────────────────┴─────────────────┴────────────────┴──────────────┘
```

Dataframe 2

```
┌────────────┬─────────────┬───────────────────┬───────────────────┬───────────┬─────────┐
│ date       ┆ org_name    ┆ org_id            ┆ org_slug          ┆ info_1    ┆ info_2  │
│ ---        ┆ ---         ┆ ---               ┆ ---               ┆ ---       ┆ ---     │
│ date       ┆ str         ┆ str               ┆ str               ┆ i64       ┆ i64     │
╞════════════╪═════════════╪═══════════════════╪═══════════════════╪═══════════╪═════════╡
│ 2023-08-29 ┆ org-name    ┆ org-id-1          ┆ org-slug-name-1   ┆ 10        ┆ 12     
└────────────┴─────────────┴───────────────────┴───────────────────┴───────────┴─────────┘
```

I'm trying to join these two dataframe based on `date`.
Then I would like to still joining via `org_id` or `org_slug` or `org_name`.

These generally match, but there are times where org_slug or org_id can be null and I want to rely on the next condition.

is it possible to achieve it in polars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your data per date is small, you might get away with an `inner join` to a `filter`. However, this can quickly explode the result set and may run out of memory.

```py
print(
    df1.join(df2, on=["date"], how="inner")
    .filter(
        pl.any_horizontal(
            pl.col("org_id") == pl.col("org_id_right"),
            pl.col("org_slug") == pl.col("org_slug_right"),
            pl.col("org_name") == pl.col("org_name_right"),
        )
    )
    .drop("org_name_right", "org_id_right", "org_slug_right")
)
```

If your data is of any significant size, it might be better suited to do multiple `left joins`, then include a `when` condition to match to the first matched `join`.

The `.with_columns(pl.lit(True).alias("joined"))` will be `null` if the join fails, or `true` if is matches.

```py
# columns we want to get from the join (e.g. info_1, info_2)
df2_columns = [c for c in df2.columns if c in set(df2.columns) - set(df1.columns)]

# expression to select the results of the first join, 
# alias the output to the first join's name
when_expr = [
    (
        # First join criteria
        pl.when(pl.col("joined").is_not_null())
        .then(pl.col(c))
        # Second join criteria
        .when(pl.col("joined_joinslug").is_not_null())
        .then(pl.col(f"{c}_joinslug").alias(c))
        # Third join criteria
        .when(pl.col("joined_joinname").is_not_null())
        .then(pl.col(f"{c}_joinname").alias(c))
    )
    for c in df2_columns
]

# Multiple left joins on the different join keys.
print(
    df1.join(
        df2.with_columns(pl.lit(True).alias("joined")),
        on=["date", "org_id"],
        how="left",
        suffix="_joinid",
    )
    .join(
        df2.with_columns(pl.lit(True).alias("joined")),
        on=["date", "org_slug"],
        how="left",
        suffix="_joinslug",
    )
    .join(
        df2.with_columns(pl.lit(True).alias("joined")),
        on=["date", "org_name"],
        how="left",
        suffix="_joinname",
    )
    .select(pl.col(df1.columns), *when_expr)
)
```

Another alternative is to loop through each key set and collect the `inner join` matches and try the remaining `anti join` results, after going through each join, concatenate the results.

```py
df2_columns = [c for c in df2.columns if c in set(df2.columns) - set(df1.columns)]
out_dfs = []
for joinkey in ["org_id", "org_slug", "org_name"]:
    out_df = df1.join(
        df2,
        on=["date", joinkey],
        how="inner",
    ).select(pl.col(df1.columns), pl.col(df2_columns))

    out_dfs.append(out_df)
    df1 = df1.join(
        df2,
        on=["date", joinkey],
        how="anti",
    )

out_df = pl.concat(out_dfs)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think [`pl.coalesce`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.coalesce.html#polars-coalesce) (picks the first non-null expression, left-to-right) will accomplish the goal here:

```py
df1.join(df2, on=['date', pl.coalesce('org_id', 'org_slug', 'org_name')])
```

This expression to join on will be primarily `org_id`, but when that is `null` on a given row, it will resolve to `org_slug` for that row, etc.

Comment: This approach assumes that the `null` values in `df1` are the exact same as `df2`. If `df1` has a `null` for `org_id`, but `df2` is not `null`, the join will fail.